# Cálculo do valor de Z da distribuição normal

Tags: java, matemática

Bom dia,
Estou a ter um problema no cálculo do valor de Z na distribuição normal.
Além disso o cálculo das constantes t e sigma t estão a dar-me 0, o que é impossivel.
Eu vou colocar o código e o output.

O calculo pode ser visto no site que se segue:
http://www.portalaction.com.br/probabilidades/62-distribuicao-normal

Certamente que em java dá para calcular, estive a fazer umas pesquisas e encontrei um método mas não está a funcionar muito bem.

O código que estou a usar é:

```
 import java.io.*;
 import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
 import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistribution;
 import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistributionImpl;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws MathException
 {        
     //constantes
     double PARAGEM=0.1; //crit. paragem função objetivo
     int ITERACOES=90; //nº max de iterações
     int ESPERA;  //tempo máximo de espera

     //variáveis
     double  A=80000; //custo de encomenda (euros)
     double C1=40000; //custo de compra (euros/ton)
     double C2=16000; //custo de stocagem (euros/ton)       
     double C3=150000; //custo de roptura (euros/ton)
     double r=44.4; //procura média (ton/ano)       
     double sigma2=0.001; //variância da procura (ton/ano)        
     double t=(60/365); //tempo medio de reposição (anos)  **//NOTA: Esta conta está a dar-me 0, não percebo porquê**
     double sigmat=(20/365); //desvio padrão do tempo de reposição (anos) **//NOTA: Esta conta está a dar-me 0, não percebo porquê**
     String distribuicao;

     //cálculo do lote otimo (diferente para a 1ª iteração)
     double Q1;
     Q1=(sqrt((2*A*r)/C2));

     //calculo de alfa
     double alfa1;
     alfa1=(C2*Q1)/C3/r;        

     //calculo de z1
     //NormalDistributionImpl recebe média, desvio padrão
     NormalDistributionImpl z1=new NormalDistributionImpl(r,sigma2);
     z1.inverseCumulativeProbability(1-alfa1);



    System.out.println("O valor de Q1 é "+ Q1);   
    System.out.println("O valor de alfa1 é "+ alfa1);  

    System.out.println("O valor de Z1 é "+ z1);
```

**Output**

O valor de Q1 é 21.071307505705477
O valor de alfa1 é 0.05062175977346662
O valor de Z1 é org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistributionImpl@36ed5ba6
O valor de t é 0.0
O valor de sigmat é 0.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pela ajuda, já consegui resolver a questão, o código correto ficaria então:

import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistribution;
import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.NormalDistributionImpl;

public class OtimizacaoDeStocks 
{

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MathException
 {
```

double A=80000.0; //custo de encomenda (euros)
         double C1=40000.0; //custo de compra (euros/ton)
         double C2=16000.0; //custo de stocagem (euros/ton)
         double C3=150000.0; //custo de roptura (euros/ton)
         double r=44.4; //procura média (ton/ano)
         double sigma2=0.0; //variância da procura (ton/ano)
         double t=(60.0/365.0); //tempo medio de reposição (anos)
         double sigmat=(20.0/365.0); //desvio padrão do tempo de reposição (anos)
         String distribuicao;

//cálculo do lote otimo (diferente para a 1ª iteração)
         double Q1;
         Q1=(sqrt((2*A*r)/C2));

```
     //calculo de alfa
     double alfa1;
     alfa1=(C2*Q1)/C3/r;        

     //calculo de z1
     NormalDistributionImpl z1=new NormalDistributionImpl(0,1);
     double z1resultado= z1.inverseCumulativeProbability(1-alfa1);         

     //calculo de m1   
     double m1;
     double mulinha= (t*r);
     double sigmalinha;
     //Ver o que se passa com sigmalinha
     sigmalinha=sqrt(sigmat*r+sigmat*r+sigmat*sigma2);
     m1= mulinha+sigmalinha*z1resultado;

    System.out.println("O valor de Q1 é "+ Q1);   
    System.out.println("O valor de alfa1 é " + alfa1);  
    System.out.println("O valor de Z1 é "+ z1resultado);
    System.out.println("O valor de mulinha é "+ mulinha);
    System.out.println("O valor de sigmalinha é "+ sigmalinha);
    System.out.println("O valor de M1 é "+ m1);


 }
```

}

**Output**

O valor de Q1 é 21.071307505705477
O valor de alfa1 é 0.05062175977346662
O valor de Z1 é 1.6388547211994033
O valor de mulinha é 7.298630136986301
O valor de sigmalinha é 2.2058452857481945
O valor de M1 é 10.913690097770177
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

As linhas...

```
double t=(60/365);
double sigmat=(20/365);
```

...estão dando zero porque você está dividindo inteiros. Tente fazer assim:

```
double t=(60.0/365.0);
double sigmat=(20.0/365.0);
```

Já a linha...

```
z1.inverseCumulativeProbability(1-alfa1);
```

...precisa guardar o resultado em uma variável:

```
NormalDistributionImpl distribuicao = new NormalDistributionImpl(r, sigma2);
double z1 = distribuicao.inverseCumulativeProbability(1-alfa1);
System.out.println("O valor de Z1 é "+ z1);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta anterior que foi bastante util.
O Z é que supostamente deveria estar a dar  1,638854721

Pois no Excel é muito mais facil, basta fazer:

INV.NORMP(1-alfa1) (no excel em português) ou  NORMSINV(1-alfa1) (no excel em inglês)
Esta função devolve o valor da função cumulativa da normal padrão.

alfa= 0.051
1-alfa=0.949
INV.NORMP(0.949)= 1.6388

Esta função não está a devolver isso, estou a ver se descubro a função equivalente em java.